# Is subdomain possible in React JS

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am creating an app which have 3 parts- Admin, Client and User. Admin has all the features, while client has some of the features while client has some. So I thought to have a common code base and will be providing access based on subdomain.

Now I could not find any suitable article across the internet for the same.

Lets say the user clicks the link `admin.company.in/login` it will open admin login page.

Similarly, `client.company.in/login` will open client's login page

How can I achieve this and also test it locally?

Comment: You could make two different build bundles for admin and client, and serve them with node express.

Answer (score 0):

React has nothing to do with this. You have to build two different react applications and server them client.company.in and admin.company.in respectively. To achieve this you have to deploy the application to the server and server with webserver (eg:nginx).